# Have data appear in first row only in one column of dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a column of ticker symbols and from that column I made a comma delimited string of symbols that was placed in a new column called v1 in the same dataframe, DF. I also took the comma delimited string to a new dataframe, DF1.  In both cases, I only wanted the string to appear in column 1, not in every column.  Is there any way in either dataframe, to have the comma delimited string of symbols only appear in the first row and not repeat in all the rows? If possible could someone explain how.  Thanks

**Delimited Comma String Code**

```
v1 = df['Ticker'].tolist()
        v1 = ",".join(map(str,v1))
        df['v1'] = v1
        df1 = df[['v1']]
        print(df)
        print (df1)
```

**Current DF Output**

```
 No. Ticker  ... AH Change                                                 v1
    0    1   AAPL  ...         -  AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    1    2   MSFT  ...         -  AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    2    3   TSLA  ...         -  AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    3    4     FB  ...         -  AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
```

**Current DF1 Output**

```
    0   AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    1   AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    2   AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    3   AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
```

**Desired DF Output**

```
   No. Ticker  ... AH Change                                                 v1
    0    1   AAPL  ...         -  AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
    1    2   MSFT  ...         -  
    2    3   TSLA  ...         -  
    3    4     FB  ...         -
```

**Desired DF1 Output**

```
    0   AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,FB,BRK-B,NVDA,TSM,JPM,V,JNJ,HD,...
```

**Full Code**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import bs4
    import time
    import random
    
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    
    def testDf(version):
        url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=sh_outstanding_o1000&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,71,72&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap'
    
        page = 1
    
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
        pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
    
        data = []
        for page in range(1, 1 * pages, 20):
            print(version, page)
            screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
            tables = pd.read_html(screen)
            tables = tables[-2]
            tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
            tables = tables[1:]
            data.append(tables)
            time.sleep(random.random())
        return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
    
    df = testDf('152').copy()
    
    
    v1 = df['Ticker'].tolist()
    v1 = ",".join(map(str,v1))
    df['v1'] = v1
    df1 = df[['v1']]
    print(df)
    print (df1)
```

Comment: Look at the `groupby` function in pandas.DataFrame. Try grouping by `v1` column.

Comment: Hi, it is already in the format I want it in, I just don't want it to repeat in every row.

Comment: Are you only concerned about the print output?

Comment: No, I'd like to use it to the ticker symbols to scrape data from an internet table.  Having it in that format, appl, msft, tesl, amzn will make it run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grouping = df.groupby('v1')

indices = []
for x in grouping.groups.values():
    indices.extend(x[1:])

df.loc[indices, 'v1'] = ''
df1 = pd.DataFrame(grouping.groups.keys())
```

Note: This changes `df` and is irreversible.